# Using two articles before and after "and"

Tags: articles

For example:

> I bought a newspaper and a magazine from the cisco.

There are two indefinite articles both in front of "newspaper" and "magazine." But I come across some literature the second article in front of "magazine" is neglected. Like,

> I bought a newspaper and magazine from the cisco.

So what is the appropriate usage of articles in this situation (The same question for the definite article "the".)

Comment: It’s a matter of how closely you want to associate the two items.